# Python Decision Tree fit method giving float error

Tags: python, decision-tree

I am using decision tree classifier.
My X(feature variables) looks like a dict:

```
{'location05': ['4425', '4436', '4425'],
 'location04': ['425', '4436', '4425','232'],
 'location03': ['4425', '4436']  }
```

my Y(target variable) is just binary.
now when i am putting them into fit method, I am getting error:

> float() argument must be a string or a number

Any help pls?

My code below:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn import tree

reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv", "rb"))
next(reader, None)
location_dict = dict()
target = []
feat = []
for line in reader:
    feat.append(line[2])
    target.append(line[3])

    if line[0] in location_dict:
        location_dict[line[0]].append(line[2])
    else:
        location_dict[line[0]] = [line[2]]
X = location_dict
y = target
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```